# Magento Sesson not showing message on product page

Tags: magento-enterprise, session

Using Wyomind Estimated Delivery Date

When I try to add too many qty then what is available for purchase it goes through and adds my message.

```
  if (!$this->checkQty($summaryQty) || !$this->checkQty($qty)) {
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
        $stock_item = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
        //$message = Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The requested quantity for "%s" is not available.', $this->getProductName());
        $message = Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('Sorry, only (%s) of item "%s" is available. Please select a new qty.', number_format($stock_item->getQty(),0),$this->getProductName());
        $result->setHasError(true)
            ->setMessage($message)
            ->setQuoteMessage($message)
            ->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
        return $result;
    } else {
```

On my local environment this bounces back on the product page and shows my error.   On my server, it bounces back and shows no message, but if I go to any other page then I see the message.

if I add

```
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);
```

before the return it will show the message twice on my product page locally and once on the server.

What causes this?

Comment: Full page cache?

Comment: I disabled cache and tried and sure enough it worked... thanks man

Comment: how can I keep messages from being cached?

Answer (score 2):

[I wrote a blogpost about this](http://blog.fabian-blechschmidt.de/messages-in-magento-only-loaded-by-default-from-core-session/) will cross post it here:

When you are working with sessions, you might have the problem, that your message is not shown.

### First add them

We have different sessions:

- core
- checkout
- sales
- customer
- admin
- a lot more.

For each of these sessions, we have four methods to add a message:

```
Mage::getSingleton('*/session')->addSuccess('Woho! It worked!');
Mage::getSingleton('*/session')->addNotice('Task was executed.');
Mage::getSingleton('*/session')->addWarning('Something went wrong.');
Mage::getSingleton('*/session')->addError('Something went horribly wrong!');
```

### And now get them

Getting the message is easy, get the right session and call `getMessages()`:

```
public function getMessages($clear=false)

Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessages(true)
```

The parameter decides whether the messages are deleted or not.

### The problem

The message block

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
<block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
```

loads only the messages of `core/session`:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php:79
public function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->addMessages(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessages(true));
    parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

There are a few places, where other session are loaded, e.g. `\Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::_renderPage`:

```
foreach (array('catalog/session', 'checkout/session', 'customer/session') as $storageType) {
    $storage = Mage::getSingleton($storageType);
    if ($storage) {
        $messageBlock->addStorageType($storageType);
        $messageBlock->addMessages($storage->getMessages(true));
    }
}
```

But unfortunately not on the product view.

### The solution

In my last project we already had an observer which makes sure, that the customer is redirected after sending a contact form, therefore we used the same method to just rewrite the message to the "correct" session.

```
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
foreach ($customerSession->getMessages()->getItems() as $message) {
    $coreSession->addMessage($message);
}
$customerSession->getMessages(true);
```

### Better(?) alternative

It is possible to just add all the messages as done in `\Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::_renderPage`.

Make sure this is done **AFTER** `$action->loadLayoutUpdates()` / `$this->loadLayoutUpdates()`